# How to get the total memory of a process which fork many children in linux with shell?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, memory

http daemon for example:

I use `ps aux|grep httpd|grep -v grep`:

```
USER     PID     RSS   COMMAND
root     14347   3220  /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14348   2400  /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14349   2400  /usr/sbin/httpd
apache   14350   2400  /usr/sbin/httpd
```

I can simple accumulate the RSS fields to get total memory usage of [httpd]. 3220+2400+2400+2400 = 10420

But i know, child processes have shared memory. There are some redundant computing here. Actually the total memory usage size may less than 10420.

My question is how to get the actually memory usage.

Comment: You might try `pmap $(pgrep httpd)` -which gives virtual memory address space information.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the actual memory usage, you need to run it within a profiler like Valgrind.

reference

http://kratos-wiki.cimne.upc.edu/index.php/Checking_memory_use_with_Valgrind

Answer (score 1):

[Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is probably your most exact choice, but can be a bit awkward to use, and is not reasonable for a production system because of performance (virtually none).

Smem ([homepage](http://www.selenic.com/smem/)) ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/smem.8.html)) is a less complicated alternative. `PSS` *process set size* is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following command, with Chrome:

```
ps aux | grep chrome | grep -v grep | awk '{s+=$5} END {print s}'
```

Note that $5 may actually vary, depending on how `ps aux` actually displays its output. This may or may not be useful to you and also displays the total usage in bytes.

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to consider shared memory which is the main concern of the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for this answer as well.
I've already found one which works.
That is running the service in a container like Docker.  Then use `docker container stats  $containerid`

Example:

```
CONTAINER ID   NAME             CPU %     MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %     NET I/O         BLOCK I/O        PIDS
329f402b9f2e   test-apache2-1   0.15%     2.677GiB / 31.01GiB   8.63%     395MB / 159MB   77.9MB / 819kB   21
```

I'm not sure which feature of containers is allowing this.  Is it cgroups? Is it namespaces?
Is there a lightweight way to do measure memory from multiple processes without requiring something like Docker or LXC?

One thing I do know is that the numbers here are accurate.  Or at least way more accurate than adding together all of the memory from ps or top.

Comment: Have you considered `memusage` and `memusagestat` (usually used in tandem).  Also `pmap` is useful if needing more fine-grained data.... It seems as though `top` would be all that was needed here.  I'm not seeing the real issue.

Comment: pmap will show you what memory space is mapped to a process.  This is very different from memory usage. Furthermore, it doesn't show memory mapped from the forked processes at all.  Top will show you mem resident and mapped from various processes, but it doesn't sum the memory of forked child processes.  I haven't tried memusage, but I'm guessing it doesn't either.

Comment: "I'm not seeing the real issue. " The issue is that many processes can share memory, either explicitly using things like shmget or implicitly using things like fork.  To me, the implicitly shared memory is even trickier to track. The example I've been looking at recently is a 250MB process that forks 19 times, so 20 processes total.  Initially, the total memory used is 250MB (I'm taking about resident memory,btw.).

Comment: Once the child processes start writing over that memory to change values, the copy-on-write feature of Linux's memory manager forces the group of processes to use even more memory, up to about 1500MB.  If you look at it in top, you'll see 20 processes each with 250MB.  If you add them all up, you would get incorrect idea of total memory used by those processes.  I recently realized that it was easy to measure using "docker container status".  See my answer for the example.  I wish there was a more light-weight way to measure this.

Comment: It would be great for things like Firefox and chrome that use shared memory.

Comment: I'm aware of all the points you listed but I wasn't aware of specifically what you are wanting achieve.  Or maybe I misunderstood/misread but using docker feels very wrong and inefficient.  I could write a shell script to parse `procfs` which will include all child processes.  Now whether you are looking for vmem, mmaps, malloc calls, etc thats can be adjusted.  So to be clear you are looking for the resident set size for all children?

Comment: >but I wasn't aware of specifically what you are wanting achieve.

Trying to see memory usage of a bunch of processes that share memory space due to forking.  I don't know how better to state it than how I already have and also the description of this question on stack overflow.

Comment: "Or maybe I misunderstood/misread but using docker feels very wrong and inefficient."


I'm sure there's a more lightweight way to do it, but I don't know if such a tool already exists.

Comment: "I could write a shell script to parse procfs which will include all child processes."

Would you care to explain how you would do that?  If you could, you could write a tool that would answer this question.

Comment: > "I don't know how better to state it than how I already have and also the description of this question on stack overflow" text doesn't carry tone but pls understand I'm not meaning to be condescending when I say this but to me this is very trivial and thats where I am repeating to just to make sure I get what you are asking.  I am going to write something up (probably in Python) just to demonstrate this.

Comment: I just finished up but the code is rough.  I will touch up and post tomorrow.

Comment: if you don't have root restrictions then I could write a solution that would be orders of magnitude more efficient with the other interface I mention.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to accomplish what you're asking here.  One involves parsing `procfs` which doesn't require "root" privileges and the other is using the [*Taskstats*](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/accounting/taskstats.txt) (a *Netlink* interface) which does.

If you can get root privileges using *Generic Netlink* sockets would be *by far* the most optimal with regards to overhead.

I have a working solution using the first solution that parses `procfs`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import time


class ShMemMonitorProcess(object):

    def __init__(self, ppid):
        self.ppid = ppid
        # Create a Sub-Class for Thread module
        self.memory = {'kB':1024, 'mB':1024*1024, 'gB':1024*1024*1024}
        self.scrape_procfs
        
    def calculate_memory(self, vmrss):
        memory, size = vmrss.split()
        return int(memory) * self.memory[size]

    @property
    def scrape_procfs(self):
        rss = 0
        child_ps = dict()
        start = time.time()
        while (time.time() - start) < 100:
            for pid in filter(lambda p: p.isdigit(), os.listdir('/proc')):
                try:
                    # open /proc/PID/status but catch as some can be ephemeral
                    with open('/proc/{}/status'.format(pid)) as fh:
                        ppid = [i for i in fh.readlines() if i.startswith('PPid')]
                        if not ppid:
                            continue
                        ppid = ppid[0].split('\t')[1].strip('\n')
                        if ppid == self.ppid:
                            with open('/proc/{}/status'.format(pid)) as fh:
                                vmrss = fh.readlines()
                                vmrss = [i for i in vmrss if i.startswith('VmRSS')]
                            if not vmrss:
                                continue
                            vmrss = vmrss[0].split('\t')[1].strip('\n')
                            ps_rss = self.calculate_memory(vmrss)
                            if not child_ps.get(pid):
                                with open('/proc/{}/comm'.format(pid)) as fh:
                                    comm = fh.readlines()
                                    print('Found Child Process {}!'.format(pid))
                                    print(comm)
                                print('Adding Process to Hash...')
                                child_ps[pid] = ps_rss
                                rss += ps_rss
                                time.sleep(1)
                            else:
                                # re-calculate process memory
                                print('Process was already found running...')
                                print('Re-calculating memory usage...')
                                previous_rss_used = child_ps[pid]
                                if previous_rss_used > ps_rss:
                                    memory_adj = previous_rss_used - ps_rss
                                    rss -= memory_adj
                                elif previous_rss_used <= ps_rss:
                                    memory_adj = ps_rss - previous_rss_used
                                    rss += memory_adj
                                child_ps[pid] = ps_rss
                            print('Bytes....{}'.format(rss))
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    continue


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Pass the Process ID through STDIN on calling
    pid = sys.argv[1]
    shmem = ShMemMonitorProcess(pid)
```

Then just calling this with the PID of what process is the "Parent" to what group you are looking to find RSS totals for.

```
python ./Find_RSS.py 1234
Found Child Process 12541!                                                                                    

22:54:40 [12/222]
['Privileged Cont\n']                                                                                                              
Adding Process to Hash...                                                                                                          
Bytes....202661888                                                                                                                 
Found Child Process 12606!                                                                                                         
['WebExtensions\n']                                                                                                                
Adding Process to Hash...                                                                                                          
Bytes....667672576                                                                                                                 
Found Child Process 12666!                                                                                                         
['Utility Process\n']                                                                                                              
Adding Process to Hash...                                                                                                          
Bytes....709660672                                                                                                                 
Found Child Process 14803!                                                                                                         
['RDD Process\n']
```